Filter Pandas dataframe column based on values in second column
I have a pandas data frame



Column A
Column B




Report 1
Vendor A


Report 1
Vendor B


Report 2
Vender C


Report 2
Vendor B


Report 3
Vendor A


Report 3
Vendor C



I'm looking for a way to exclude any reports that Vender A appears on. The correct output should be



Column A
Column B




Report 2
Vendor C


Report 2
Vendor B



So far, I've tried using multi-index and groupby, but whenever I filter, I'm only seeing the rows that exclude Vendor A, not the multi-level.
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.read_excel('Expense Data.xlsx', sheet_name='FY23')

cols = ['Column A', 'Column B']
grouped_df = df.set_index(cols)

grouped_df.xs('Vendor A', level='Vendor', drop_level=False)

print(grouped_df.loc[~grouped_df.index.get_level_values(1).str.contains("Vendor A", na=False)])


You don't need multi-index and groupby, just simply use the filtering:
`df[df["Vendor"]!="Vendor A"]`


One option among many: df.loc[~df['Column A'].isin(df.loc[df['Column B'].eq('Vendor A'), 'Column A'])]

Here is another approach using groupby which gives the desired result: df.groupby('Column A').filter(lambda x: all(x['Column B'].ne('Vendor A')))

@ Vardan Grigoryants : there is no column Vendor; also even if changed to Column B this would not remove all the Report 1 and Report 3 rows because Column A is not being taken into account.
